# Text right next to a div or span won't work, how can I fix this?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get my text next to a square div/span.

I've tried a div, then float with the text; I also tried a span with display: inline-block and display:block. I can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong. Already searched on Stack Overflow, but those solutions don't seem to work for me.

Here is the code I use:

```css
.event-date{
 background-color: #2C3846;
 color: white;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.event-text{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
 <body>
   <div class="main-container">
     <section class="col-content">
       <main>
         <h1>Onze evenementen</h1>
           <section>
             <div class="event-date">9<br>apr</div>
             <h2 class="event-text">Discussiebijeenkomst Europa</h2>
                <p class="event-text"><q>Wat betekent Europa nu concreet voor mij, in mijn dagelijks leven als 
            ...</q></p>
            </main>
          </section>
        </div>
      </body>
```

I want the 'h2' and the 'p' stuff next to the blue square. it's going to be like an event list, and the blue box is the date.

Comment: Sorry, new here and can't seem to get the full link there. English isn't my first language so didn't fully understand the error message the site gave me.. :/

Comment: You need to add the code on-site. Keeping it off-site will only get the question closed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Please edit your question to include your code *directly* in the question in the form of a [mcve]. The site is blockin you from adding the full link to JSFiddle because questions about debugging (e.g. questions that commonly link to a JSFiddle demo) are required to have that code here as part of the question. That way, when the JSFiddle link dies, this question doesn't lose its value.

Comment: float should come first here https://jsfiddle.net/ghf8o9Lc/

Comment: thanks for helping me out, I'm sorry it went wrong!

Comment: @MaximeLaunois please don't add pejorative/opinionated content when suggesting edits.

Comment: @TylerH I didn't checked what was the text about, I added the code from the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ghf8o9Lc/) as-is... Should I replace it with other, neutral text?

Comment: @MaximeLaunois It looks like you were editing from an old revision; the revision history shows you "adding" the line about "I'm a student so my code is horribly written". Turns out that was removed (correctly) earlier on by another user. In the future, that can probably be avoided by refreshing the page before applying any revision (if, for example, you've had the 'edit' view open for a while). Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's pretty simple, you have the main div, which will include both, the date and the text. You put the float on the wrong class, as the element that'll go after the div will be the text, so you have to add `float: left;` to the date div. Nevertheless, you'll have something like this :

```css
.event-date {
 background-color: #2C3846;
 color: white;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 20px;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.event-text {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main-container">
   <section class="col-content">
    <main>
     <h1>Onze evenementen</h1>
     <section>
      <div class="event-date">9<br>apr</div>
      <br><h2 class="event-text">Discussiebijeenkomst Europa</h2>
      <p class="event-text"><q>Wat betekent Europa nu concreet voor mij, in mijn dagelijks leven als 
            ...</q></p>
     </section>
    </main>
   </section>
  </div>
 </body>
```

I addded simply `float: left;` to the date div, got rid of the padding and margin of the text (to fit better the date space) and added a `<br>` to break the upper empty space that would put the text too much on top (see it before the `<h2>` mark). Hope it helped. If you wish also, here's the a Fiddle too :

[JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7th36anL/)

Answer (score 1):

You can amend this simply by displaying the date and text inline-block

```css
.event-date, .event-text{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

If you want the date to float to the left of the text, add `float:left` to the date CSS.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/uk76ye3s/)